# What is considered a Digital Filter

Tags: digital-filters

Would upscaling from a DVD to 4k on a TV be considered Digital Filtering?
Would an AI trained to suppress noise and enhanced desired signal be considered a Digital Filter?

I'm trying to figure out what counts as Digital filtering and what does not.

> In signal processing, a digital filter is a system that performs mathematical operations on a sampled, discrete-time signal to reduce or enhance certain aspects of that signal.

By this definition from Wikipedia I would think so but I am not sure if I am being too open in my interpretation.

Or does the original signal have to be analog?

I have found no real list on this. Just the definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would upscaling from a DVD to 4k on a TV be considered Digital Filtering?

No, that's scaling. It might involve filtering, especially for *anti-imaging*.

> Would an AI trained to suppress noise and enhanced desired signal be considered a Digital Filter?

It might. Does it filter? That's a bit up to definition. For example, a lot of voice codecs are designed to suppress noise and enhance intelligibility of the encoded speech.

There's machine learning-designed codecs of that kind. A central part in many such efficient representations of audio is that they reproduce something that *sounds like it contains the same information* from the space-efficient representation, but is really not just a filtering (in *my* opinion!) because they effectively re-synthesize what was said – they don't take a "full" audio recording and just suppress some part and emphasize some other.

Putting a low-pass filter after a microphone to reduce the noise and make the voice of someone telling a story is filtering. Using AI to write down what was said (e.g. as syllables and intonation), and sending the resulting book to another machine for that to "read out" the story isn't really filtering anymore.

Such definitions of "what constitutes a filter" are subjective. All human language is. You'll have to live with a bit of ambiguity. All you can do is be precise when defining what *you* mean with "filtering" when it really matters.

> Or does the original signal have to be analog?

no.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful! I am fine with a bit of ambiguity. I only just recently was introduced to Digital Filters and was not sure of their scope.

Answer (score 0):

I’d say that the «core» meaning of a digital filter is a linear time-invariant FIR or IIR (recursive) signal processing operation, or equivalent operations carried out by FFT topologies. By multiplying and adding a signal to a neighbourhood or to the filter output, one can modify a waveform. Central is that one can identify certain goals in the time or frequency domain (such as «pulse shaping», «bass boost» or similar).

If the filter weights are updated adaptively, the filter is no longer time invariant, but I would still say that it is a filter. If a nonlinearity is not only a secondary effect (such as the unsharp mask operation), but a central effect in itself (such as a compressor/limiter), I would say that it is no longer a filter.

A Voltera filter does some sort of convolution on a set of linear (of various order) components and cross components.